# Sorting characters without using the sort in unix

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

Hey so I'm extremely new to unix, and I grasp the basics, but I'm stuck at this one part.

So I'm to input values (letters) and sort them, without using the sort method. I considered changing the values of the letters to ACSII values and using if statements in that manner.

Is this the right way to go about this? I know this is how you do it for numbers

```
echo Enter 2  numbers with spaces in between
read a b 
l=$a
if [ $b -gt $l ]
then
l=$b
fi
echo Largest of $a $b is $l
```

so I'm ASSUMING converting them to values would make sense. I know in java I would do something similar. Again, I'm pretty new.

Answer (score 2):

[test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html), e.g., "[" and "]" assumes the operands are integers, which does not sound like what you want. [expr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expr.html) can sort letters, using syntax like

```
if expr $b \> $l
```

I ran into an amusing problem with a shell which confused the two - see [my notes](http://invisible-island.net/autoconf/portability-test.html)